# wp-die-message / change the output link

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, hyperlink

So I am having some trouble in finding and editing this particular thing. Here is the error:

`Sorry, you have reached the download limit allowed for this file. Go to store`

The `Go to store` is a link and I want to change it, change the location. It currently redirects to the store page, but I want to redirect the user to the home(page) instead.

So my question is: **Where can I change the store link (which is outputed in that error) to the home(page) link instead?**

Cheers!

Comment: If you search the WooCommerce code repo for that phrase, it appears in one place only, https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b19500728b4b292562afb65eb3a0c0f50d5859de/includes/class-wc-download-handler.php#L156 The method `download_error` is at the very end of that file, but it does not appear to offer any hooks to change the functionality.

Comment: It calls `wc_get_page_permalink` to create the link, and that one is hook-able - but if you do that, you likely will only be able to change _all_ the places where the system links to the shop page, because in this place you will have no context to identify this “special situation”. Might perhaps make the most sense, if you simply changed that link via JavaScript, after the page has loaded.